# Article was not published within agreed time, how do you avoid/handle this situation?

Tags: publishing, freelance, electronic-publishing

Recently I ran into a situation where an accepted article (by an online publication) was not published the month it was agreed on.

The article had time-sensitive paragraphs for events that would expire within months. So it can be considered to be an article with an expiration date.

Finally, I decided to take my article and publish it elsewhere (the publisher/editor claimed to have "lost" the article).

Now I would like to understand what other writers have experienced in these situations?

- **If you sell an article that should be published before a certain time period, can you argue for payment at the point of sale?**
  -- Instead of "when the article is published", as is suggested by several online outlets.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in your publishing contract. (In the absence of a contract, the written communication between you and your publisher can serve as an agreement and stand in for a contract.) If the contract (or a written agreement) was breached and you lost a significant amount of money, consult a lawyer.